# product of multiple selected columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a subset of variables that starts with 'AA_' (e.g., AA_1, AA_2, ... AA_100) along with other variables X, Y, Z.

If I would like to get the produce of all 'AA_' variables, what would be the most efficient way in R to achieve this?

I am thinking something like

```
mydata = mydata %>% 
  mutate(AA_product = reduce(starts_with('AA_'), `*`))
```

but it does not quite work

Answer (score 1):

Here, we need to select the data

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mydata %>% 
        mutate(AA_product = reduce(select(., starts_with( 'AA_')), `*`))
```

-output

```
#   X Y Z AA_1 AA_2 AA_3 AA_product
#1 1 2 3    1    2    3          6
#2 2 3 4    2    3    4         24
#3 3 4 5    3    4    5         60
```

---

Another less efficient approach is `rowwise` with `c_across`

```
mydata %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(AA_prod = prod(c_across(starts_with('AA')))) %>%
    ungroup
```

#### data

```
mydata <- data.frame(X = 1:3, Y = 2:4, Z = 3:5,
           AA_1 = 1:3, AA_2 = 2:4, AA_3 = 3:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want row-wise product for `"AA_"` columns, you can do this in base R with `Reduce` :

```
cols <- grep('AA_', names(mydata))
mydata$AA_product <- Reduce(`*`, mydata[cols])
```

and `apply` :

```
mydata$AA_product <- apply(mydata[cols], 1, prod)
```